# How to turn off automatic rounding in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, rounding

My code:

```
public class klas {
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int a=5, b=4;
        double c=0;
        c=a / b;
        System.out.println ("a/b=c");
        System.out.println (a+ " / " + b + " = " + c);

    }

}
```

My output:

```
 a/b=c
 5 / 4 = 1.0
```

Desired output: 0.2.

How to fix it?

Comment: Very poor mathematics :p 
And how is **1+1 = 5**

Comment: Will You please explain How Your desired result be 0.2 ?

Answer (score 4):

You would never get 0.2 when dividing 5 by 4, but you could get 1.25 with :

```
c = (double)a/b;
```

Without the casting to double, a/b is evaluated as a division of two integers, and therefore the result is also an integer.

Comment: @SonalPM You can't always get what you want, but if you try sometime, you get what you need

Comment: That's the answer I want. I was experimenting with this new language and a lot of numbers. I'm sorry for confusion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are performing integer math; the result of dividing two integers is an `int`. Secondly, you are asking for a result that is 2/10. That is equivalent to 1/5. So,

```
double c = 1 / (double) 5;
System.out.printf("%.1f%n", c);
```

Output is (the requested)

```
0.2
```